# JSON test interface for learning JSON

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've a iphone project to do in the future that will involve retrieving data from a Database via JSON.
So I plan to spend the next week learning as much about JSON as i can. I was wonder have any of you ever come across some JSON interface you can use for testing/learning to make the calls against and handle the returned data? I want to practice and learn before I try and handle a real project. And I guess I cannot write test apps using JSON if I've nothing to test with.

Also if there is a particular tutorial you've found really worth while I'd appreciate a mention of it. Just going through google at the moment reading what I find.

Thanks
-Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here and here and here

Google JSON Tutorial
http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=json+tutorial

JSON in 3 Minutes
http://secretgeek.net/json_3mins.asp

SBJSON Code - A lot easier to learn and use
http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/

Answer (score 0):

In order to work with JSON in your IPhone project, you should look at https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON or http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/
About testing data you can simply create your JSON response text and retrieve call to get it then parsing. In addition, you can use interface from twitter, Facebook, or Flickr, etc.
Hope that help.

Comment: So you reckon that Twitter and Facebook etc have databases exposed that I can test JSON calls against? Thats awesome TY